# Pass Member Function as Parameter to other Member Function (C++ 11 <function>)

Tags: c++, function, c++11, std-function, member-functions

Let's say that I have a class with three member functions, as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class ClassName
{
  public:
    double add(double a, double b);
    double intermediate(double a, double b, std::function<double (double,double)> func);
    double combiner(double a, double b);
};

double ClassName::add(double a, double b)
{
  return a+b;
}

double ClassName::intermediate(double a, double b, std::function<double (double,double)> func)
{
  return func(a, b);
}

double ClassName::combiner(double a, double b)
{
  return intermediate(a, b, add);
}

int main()
{
  ClassName OBJ;
  std::cout << OBJ.combiner(12, 10);
}
```

What I'm wanting to do is pass the member function "add" to the member function "intermediate" which is then called by "combiner."  However, I don't think that I'm using the right syntax, because when I attempt to compile this, I get an error saying "non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member."
I'm not quite sure what's going wrong, because this method works perfectly if these functions are not member functions in a class (just regular functions defined in the namespace).  **So is it possible to pass a member function to another member function?**

Comment: `return intermediate(a, b, [this](double x, double y) { return add(x, y); } );`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`ClassName::add` is a non-static member function, an instance of `ClassName` is needed for it to be called on; it can't be used as the argument for `std::function<double (double,double)>` directly.

You can use [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and capture `this` (as @Igor Tandetnik commented):

```
return intermediate(a, b, [this](double x, double y) { return add(x, y); } );
```

or use [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and bind `this` pointer:

```
return intermediate(a, b, std::bind(&ClassName::add, this, _1, _2));
```

or make `ClassName::add` a static member function or a non-member function (it could be because it doesn't use any members of `ClassName`). e.g.

```
class ClassName
{
  public:
    static double add(double a, double b);
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that wasn't something that I had realized yet.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 8):

If you truly want to pass the member function, you need a [member function pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members)

```
class ClassName
{
   public:
    double add(double a, double b);
    using Combiner = double (ClassName::*)(double, double);
    double intermediate(double a, double b, Combiner);
    double combiner(double a, double b);
};
```

This will only slightly change the implementation of `intermediate` and `combiner`

```
double ClassName::intermediate(double a, double b, Combiner func)
{
  return (this->*func)(a, b);
}

double ClassName::combiner(double a, double b)
{
  return intermediate(a, b, &ClassName::add);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also a very good solution.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: @JohnTravolski Just be aware that std::function usually has a big overhead, both runtime and for the compiler and object layout. Compared to those, Member-Pointers are very compiler friendly and have the space requirements of any integer.

Comment: I appreciate the heads-up.  Thank you.

Comment: @JohnTravolski Link to member function pointers explanation added